# Vim No GUI and clipboard

Tags: gnome, vim, clipboard

I have Gnome Ubuntu 14.04 and I reinstalled vim (without GUI, I did not enable gui because I don't think I need it) and replaced netrw with the latest to have `:Lexplorer`. Now when I use vim's File Explorer (netrw), I get this error when I open a file or a folder:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>32_NetrwBrowseChgDir..<SNR>32_NetrwOptionRestore:  
line   69:  
E354: Invalid register name: '*'
```

After many times googling, people say I need clipboard support for vim to fix it. Do I need to compile vim with GUI to have clipboard support? Or is it possible to enable clipboard without GUI and I just need to add some flags during configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to compile vim with clipboard support.

Try to install last version of `netrw`. Download vimball using [this link](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vbafiles/netrw.vba.gz)

After that open this file using **vim** `vim netrw.vba.gz` and type this:

```
:so %
:q
```

This will install new version of netrw plugin. I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Hi, the netrw you provided requires patch 213. I am now cloning vim from git but it is too big. Do you know where I can find a compressed latest vim? All I can find is the plain old vim7.4. Thanks.

Comment: Found [this](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev) ppa with vim 7.4.335

Comment: The cloning finished with 130mb size. I'll just use that ppa when I need to reinstall vim in the future. Thank you.